# excel: lookup a range for a key, find multiple matches, return the last match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In the example below the A column contains keys and 
the B column contains values.

I want to search for the key 
"aaa", and return the last match's value: "aug".

In this case there are 3 instances of the "aaa" key, but there
could be just 1 instance, or many (unknown) number of "aaa"
keys. I'm always interested in just the the last match.

No additional columns can be added. The columns are not sorted.

**vlookup()** returns the first match ("jan") and I haven't been able to make it work in conjunction with other functions to return the last match.

Thanks.

```
           A     B     C    ...

        +-----+-----+
  1     | aaa | jan |
        +-----+-----+
  2     |  b  | feb |
        +-----+-----+
  3     |  c  | mar |
        +-----+-----+
  4     | aaa | apr |
        +-----+-----+
  5     |  d  | jun |
        +-----+-----+
  6     |  e  | jul |
        +-----+-----+
  7     | aaa | aug |
        +-----+-----+
  8     |  f  | sep |
        +-----+-----+
  9     |  g  | oct |
        +-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please write the array formula below.

`=index(B1:B9, max(if(a1:a9="aaa", row(a1:a9))))`

then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>

Comment: What if the range does not begin in row 1? For example, what does your formula give if we change the ranges A1:A9 and B1:B9 to e.g. E6:E14 and F6:F14?

Comment: @XORLX, in your case `indirect()` is needed.  The array formula would be like `=index(F6:F14, max(if(E6:E14="aaa", row(indirect("1:"&rows(E6:E14)) ))))`.  In fact, your answer teach me a new lesson.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually use of the volatile INDIRECT is not necessary. You need to think how to generalise your solution such that the correct parameter is passed to INDEX for the row_num,

Comment: @XORLX, to avoid volatile function, I try `=INDEX(F6:F14,MAX(IF(E6:E14="aaa",ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(E6:E14))))))`

Comment: Why not simply =INDEX(F:F,MAX(IF(E6:E14="aaa",ROW(E6:E14))))? The point is that your posted formula is almost there; it's just that you need to adjust to account for the row_num parameter in INDEX. If we insist on a set-up which refers to the specified rows only (e.g. within an Excel table), then =INDEX(F6:F14,MAX(IF(E6:E14="aaa",ROW(E6:E14)-MIN(ROW(E6:E14))+1))).

Comment: @XORLX, This is my first time bypass the `Indirect()` function.  You give me a new direction to think.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`=LOOKUP(1,0/(A1:A9="aaa"),B1:B9)`

Regards